# What is Contract Terminate?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, ink, smart-contract

Is `contract terminate` means `stop the currently executed smart contract` or `delete it from Blockchain?`. `If terminate means stop`, then will it be resume later and `If terminate means delete from blockchain`, then will it delete from every distributed, decentralized blockchain network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

calling `terminate` on a contract will:

- send all of its fund to the beneficiary
- delete its address (it will be inaccessible)
- remove all of its storage

Source:
[Substrate repo 1](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f465fee723c87b7348839b5140135b17d0a48743/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L280)
[substrate repo 2](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f465fee723c87b7348839b5140135b17d0a48743/frame/contracts/src/exec.rs#L156)

Comment: Calling terminate did transfer all the funds from the `contract` to the user who called `terminate`. However the funds that got reserved on the wallet while deploying the contract, are still reserved.
Do you know how that can be moved back to free balance?